# SQL Query Syntax ERROR 1064

Tags: syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I will to execute this query :

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_appconfig` (`appid` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `configkey` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `configvalue` CLOB DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`appid`, `configkey`));
```

But I have this error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLOB DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`appid`, `configkey`))' at line 1

Have you a explication ? Thanks for your help
EwKilian